# How do I declare a list in YAML and read using PERL YAML::XS

Tags: perl, yaml

I can create a value in YAML as such:

```
MYVAL: 1
```

I can load this in my PERL as follows:

```
my $settings = YAML::XS::LoadFile...
my $number_mine = $settings->{'MYVAL'};
```

I would want to create now an array of strings in YAML. 
I tried using - and --- but not seeing it

YAML?

```
MYARRAY: str1,str2,str3
```

PERL:

```
my @array_mine = $settings->{'MYARRAY'};
```

Comment: See [yaml.org](https://yaml.org/)

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
MYARRAY: str1,str2,str3
```

is a YAML mapping, the same way as your

```
MYVAL: 1
```

is a YAML mapping. The difference is that the value for the key `MYARRAY` is a plain (i.e. non quoted) scalar string `str1,str2,str3` and for the value `MYVAL` is the scalar integer `1`

If you want a sequence of three strings as value on a single line, you would need to do:

```
MYARRAY: [str1,str2,str3]
```

(optionally with whitespace before and/or after the commas). That is a flow style sequence of three plain scalars: `str1`, `str2` and `str3`.

An alternative is to use block style:

```
MYARRAY: 
- str1
- str2
- str3
```

which is semantically equivalent to the flow style example above.

Answer (score 2):

Dump out a list and see what it looks like:

```
$ perl -MYAML -E 'say YAML::Dump( { MYARRAY => ["str1","str2","str3"] })'
---
MYARRAY:
  - str1
  - str2
  - str3
```

Comment: I think I am getting confused on the PERL load into variable and access say first element. I actually had above but thought it was wrong.

Comment: The leading whitespace in front of the list elements is important.

Comment: @mob no, the leading spaces before the dashes are not important. Practically all YAML libraries can parse it without leading spaces. The dashes are counting as indentation.